# Reproduce network architectures with Java from a trained keras .h5 model

Tags: library, java, python, deep-learning

I’m trying to open an already trained model from Keras (python) with Java and use it to analyze new images. My model is saved in HDF5 format which contains the architecture of the network as a .json file and the trained weights as .h5.

In FIJI it is easy to read each of the weight matrices in my network. However, I didn’t find any script to reproduce the architecture of the network without using Keras.

Using DL4J it is possible to reproduce the graph but is it also possible to complete this graph with the weights and process an image? Is there any other Java library which can read the dictionary from .json and build the architecture in a way that I know how to process my image with the trained weights in Java?

Might it be done already for Fiji, CellProfiler or Ilastik?

Thanks a lot!